# Dometic cfx50w fridge - how to choose small DIY battery setup

Tags: power-supply, batteries

I am looking for some help to understand what kind of battery could power a Dometic cfx50w 12/24/120V compressor fridge, while on-the-go. Here are the electrical specifications:

> Input voltage (AC) 120-240 V
>   Input voltage (DC) 12/24 V
>   Rated input current (AC) 0.79 A
>   Rated input current (DC) 7.8 A
>   Input frequency 50/60 Hz

([Link to full fridge specifications](https://www.dometic.com/en-ca/ca/products/food-and-beverage/coolers/electric-coolers/dometic-cfx-50w-_-152178#specifications))

Most people choose a dual battery DC/DC setup for their car. I am looking for a more compact and portable solution, to get a few hours (minimum 4) running in normal conditions. I am thinking of a battery pack like those used in the RC hobby. Would this work?

I am looking for best battery chemistry and recommended ah rating considering the fridge would run for 10 minutes every hour and battery would have to provide 4 hours of power without getting damaged. Fridge has a cutoff voltage of 11.1v. I am wondering if lipo or lifepo4 batteries could replace a flooded lead acid and what would be the usable capacity. Battery would be charged at home by small rc charger.

Comment: Answers to the duplicate question show how the calculations are done. As in that question, the product specification is not clear about the current. I think you can assume that the 7.8 A is for 12 volts, but that is uncertain. What is the best battery chemistry may be a matter of opinion. Comparing useable capacity is an interesting problem.

Comment: Usable capacity is an issue. Here are my calculations based on the previously answered question. Correct me if am wrong please. Fridge power usage when always running 12V*7.8A=93.6W 20000mah lipo battery has ~20*12=240Wh